# adding a class on click of Anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lets say I have the following HTML...

```
<a class="active" href="#section1">Link 1</a>  
<a href="#section2">Link 2</a>
```

When a link 2 is clicked I would like it to receive the active class and remove the class from link 1 itself so it would effectively become:

```
<a href="#section1">Link 1</a>  
<a class="active" href="#section2">Link 2</a>
```

This should work both ways. Ie. whatever link is clicked gets the class and removes it from the other.

How can this be done with jQuery?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $("a.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Edit: added jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LJ6L5/

Comment: It is not ideal at all to activate every anchor element on the page. It uses a lot of memory and is probably not UX/UI friendly.

Comment: Well according to your original post, you only have 2 anchors.

Comment: any way your solution was shortest and i will modify it according to my needs...thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

Just use: [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

But first limit your activable links with second class ('activable') to not affect other links on page:

```
$("a.activable").click(function(){
   $("a.activable.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

With HTML:

```
<a class="activable active" href="#section1">Link 1</a>  
<a class="activable" href="#section2">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: @gertas-sorry for not explaining problem, actually at the first time none of the links having any class, on a first click i have to add a class to that link and then it should work in the same way as i said in question?

Comment: Just leave out `active`. If you don't use a `activable` class, then every anchor on the page will fall into the use of active links.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a class="myrefclass" href="#section1">Link 1</a>  
<a class="myrefclass active" href="#section2">Link 2</a>
```

JS:

```
var ref = $("a.myrefclass");
$(ref).bind('click', function() {

   if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

      $(ref).removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active);
   }

});
```

JS II (for comment):

```
var ref = $("a.myrefclass");
$(ref).bind('click', function(ev) {

   if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      ev.stopPropagation();
      return false;
   }

   $(ref).removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active);

});
```

Comment: what if, i have already called a function on onclick of these links

Comment: but in this case, you have to do tests to see if first calls the event "onClick" in diferent browsers, if you do it with jQuery, you create another event after the control