# jQuery. Switching between elements

Tags: jquery, toggle, switch-statement

I have this html code

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<div>Content</div>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<div>Content</div>
```

and this jQuery

```
$('a').click(
function(){
    $("div:visible").slideUp(100),
    $(this).next("div:hidden").slideDown(100),
    $('a').css({"font-weight" : "normal"}),
    $(this).css({"font-weight" : "bold"});
});
```

The idea is that after I click the link next div becomes visible. Link itself becomes **bold**. Click on the another link hides any visible div, removes bold from any link and opens new div and makes another link bold.

Quite simple and works ok with only one exception: after I click the same link second time I don't need it to be **bold**. I understand that this happens because of the last line of the jQuery code but can't find another solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you actually want the link to change from bold to normal on a 2nd click?  Or just to remain as bold?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the current link is already bold.  If not, then make it so.

```
if ($(this).css("font-weight") != "bold") {
  $(this).css({"font-weight" : "bold"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `toggleClass()` in this case

in your css write this-

```
.normal{"font-weight" : "normal"}
.bold{"font-weight" : "bold"}
```

in jquery -

```
$('a').click(  function(){ 

$('a.bold').removeClass('bold'); // will remove bold class from all link   

$("div:visible").slideUp(100),     
 $(this).next("div:hidden").slideDown(100)      

$(this).toggleClass('normal bold') ;

});
```

Comment: Needs quotes around the list of classnames I think

Comment: That's cool, but in this case toggle isn't applicable. When I click the link twice it works as I need. But if I click another link, the first one don't become "normal".

Comment: so in that case what you can do is- assign a class to currently clicked link and when you clicked on different link remove class from previous link and assigned this class to current link

Comment: you can refer this post as i have done the similar thing-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647098/adding-a-class-on-click-of-anchor-tag

Comment: Isn't that assigning of classes the same thing I do here but in different words: `$('a').css({"font-weight" : "normal"}),
    $(this).css({"font-weight" : "bold"});`

Comment: yeah, but in addition to that you have to check also on every click that classes are assigned or not..you can have look at `hasClass()` too. see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery.data function to store metadata about DOM elements.

So in your case, change last line:

```
$(this).css({"font-weight" : "bold"});
```

to:

```
if ($(this).data('clicked') == undefined) $(this).css({"font-weight" : "bold"});
$(this).data('clicked', true);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice solution, but this only work once. After I click the link third time it don't become bold.

Comment: Can I delete that data, after the link is clicked second time? I think this would let make it bold again.